# How Change StringProperty Subtype with a Button?

Tags: python, properties

The Blender API Allows you to create a property to insert a "Hidden" text useful for example to use for Password. This is possible by entering a parameter `subtype='PASSWORD'` like this, declared in the addon preferences:

```
password: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype='PASSWORD')
```

Then to display in a panel:

```
layout.prop(preferences, 'password', text = "Password")
```

[image]

I would like to also be able to show a button to make show / hide the password, but I really don't know how to do it, since that property seems to be declared when Blender starts.

Comment: Possibly the easiest way to do this is to declare another prop without and swap them, rather than re defining the property, which is AFAIK the only way to change any of the attributes.  Comes up with `min` and `max` a lot.

Comment: Hello @batFINGER It would be nice to see an example. I think it might be a valid answer to my question.

Comment: Just declare two string properties and one bool, in your layout display one of the string properties based on the bool property, should be pretty straight forward right?

Comment: @brockmann I think it's that simple, but you should correctly update all 2 properties every time you change 1 or the other, relative to the subtype password and the non-subtype password.

Comment: `get()`, `set()` @NoobCat?

Comment: @brockmann Definitely a smart way, but I think it can be useful for the community to see a practical example.

Comment: Why waiting for it? ;) @NoobCat

Comment: @brockmann Because I've never quite understood get / set method, and I'm not sure how to do it in this case (I feel part of a fairly noob slice of comunity)